# Erro de compilação com structs

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados, compilação

O seguinte erro está acontecendo na compilação do código abaixo:

> ..\src\struct.cpp:19:19: error: elements of array 'main()::ficaha v [3]' have incomplete type
>   ..\src\struct.cpp:19:19: error: storage size of 'v' isn't known

Código:

```ccp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define N 3
struct ficha{
    string nome;
    int idade;
    int reg;
};

int main() {
    struct ficaha v[3];
    int id;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cout << "\n\nDgite o NOME do aluno " << i;
        getline(cin,v[i].nome);
        cout << "\n\nDgite a IDADE do aluno " << i;
        cin >> v[i].idade;
        cout << "\n\nDgite o REGISTRO do aluno " << i;
        cin >> v[i].reg;
    }
    cout << "Digite uma idade: ";
    cin >> id;
    cout <<"\nDados dos alunos com idade menor que "<<id<<": "<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if ((v[i].idade) < id){
            cout << v[i].nome << " - " << v[i].idade;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Este é meu primeiro exercício de `structs` e aparentemente fiz exatamente como aprendi e não estou enxergando nenhum erro no código.

Desde já agradeço pela atenção!

Comment: ficaha? Acho que para chamar a estrutura deve-se por o mesmo nome declarado previamente.

Answer (score 2):

## ficaha

O erro de compilação é bastante claro e explicativo:

> ..\src\struct.cpp:19:19: error: elements of array 'main()::**ficaha** v [3]' have incomplete type

E você tem isso no código:

```
struct ficha{
...
struct ficaha v[3];
```

E obviamente "*ficha*" e "*fic***a***ha*" são dois nomes completamente diferentes para o compilador, "*ficaha*" é um erro de digitação.